# sql query search by anchored field

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me plz, this sql not workin

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM p_pl 
 WHERE (`sid` = '25' AND `value` = 'zxc') 
   AND (`sшd` = '22' AND `value` = 'cxz')
```

this sql workin:

```
 SELECT * FROM p_pl WHERE (`sid` = '25' AND `value` = 'zxc')
```

How make query? thanks

Comment: Please do not ask for help and use the phrase "This is not working". This is extremely unhelpful for anyone trying to help. Describe what is not working. Is it throwing an error? Is it producing results, but they are incorrect? Try to be as specific as possible about what "is not working"

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: How can value be **both** `'zxc'` and `'cxz'`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want `OR` ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM p_pl 
WHERE (`sid` = '25' AND `value` = 'zxc') 
   OR (`sid` = '22' AND `value` = 'cxz')
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `OR`:

```
select *
from p_pl
where  (`sid` = '25' and `value` = 'zxc')
    or (`sid` = '22' and `value` = 'cxz')
```

Or simply:

```
select *
from p_pl
where (sid, value) in(('25','zxc'),('22','cxz'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you be using 'OR' instead of 'AND'?

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM p_pl 
 WHERE (`sid` = '25' AND `value` = 'zxc') 
   OR(`sшd` = '22' AND `value` = 'cxz')
```